# File encoding commande

Tags: php, type-conversion, file-encodings

I have 1200 files encoded ANSI. I need to convert them into UTF-8. It is not reasonable to convert each file using the simple solution file/save as!
Is there a commande in php which convert files from ANSI to UTF-8?

Comment: I use Windows and not Unix

Comment: ANSI = ASCII to you?

Comment: it corresponds to ISO  encoding I think

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using php? There are tons of similar questions on SO (and probably elsewhere) with solutions in many languages… There are also similar questions on [su], like [this one](http://superuser.com/q/113394)

Comment: ISO? Okay. There are only a few dozen of those encoding.

Comment: I am not very  good in java but I will try the code mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the iconv library, which has a PHP binding (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).  Consider using the command-line program to convert your source files instead, and keeping everything in utf8 instead of juggling encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution using PHP.
This is the code used:

```
<?php
 set_time_limit ( 30000 );
$k=0;
while ($k<1232)
{
   $fres="contenu_url".$k.".txt";
   $inF = fopen($fres,"r");     
   $fres1="contenu_utf".$k.".txt";
   $OutF = fopen($fres1,"w+");  
   $k=$k+1;
   if($inF == false)
     echo "<p>Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier</p>.\n";
   $contenu_ancien="";
   while (!feof($inF)) 
                    $contenu_ancien .= fgets($inF, 4096);

   $contenu_utf8 = utf8_encode ($contenu_ancien);
        fputs($OutF,$contenu_utf8);
   fclose($OutF);   fclose($inF);
    }

 ?>
```